# Canvas visualization with Web Audio API works on major browsers except Safari

Tags: javascript, html, safari, html5-canvas, web-audio-api

I have this code to visualize the audio. I mean visualizing by the Web Audio API and HTML canvas element:

```js
window.MyNamespace = {} // Easy access to some vars by namespace.

// Some browsers require a user gesture before creating Web Audio API context.
MyNamespace.firstUserGesture = true

MyNamespace.audio = {}

MyNamespace.audio.el = document.getElementById("aud")

MyNamespace.audio.canvasEl = document.getElementById("canvasEl")

function setupCanvas() {
  MyNamespace.audio.canvasEl.style.width = "88%"
  MyNamespace.audio.canvasEl.style.height = "100px"

  // High dpi stuff.
  // Controls the chart line stroke thickness.
  MyNamespace.audio.canvasEl.width = 500 * 2
  MyNamespace.audio.canvasEl.height = 100 * 2

  // Get canvas context.
  MyNamespace.audio.canvasCtx = MyNamespace.audio.canvasEl.getContext("2d")

  // Set stroke color.
  MyNamespace.audio.canvasCtx.strokeStyle = "#4285F4"

  // Draw twice as thick lines due to high dpi scaling.
  MyNamespace.audio.canvasCtx.lineWidth = 2

  // Animation reference.
  MyNamespace.audio.canvasAnimation = {}

  MyNamespace.audio.el.addEventListener('play', () => drawWave())
  MyNamespace.audio.el.addEventListener('pause', () => cancelAnimationFrame(MyNamespace.audio.canvasAnimation))
  MyNamespace.audio.el.addEventListener('ended', () => cancelAnimationFrame(MyNamespace.audio.canvasAnimation))

  let N = 0 // Data count to show.
  N = MyNamespace.audio.analyzer.fftSize
  MyNamespace.audio.data = new Uint8Array(N)

  // Our drawing method
  function drawWave() {
    MyNamespace.audio.analyzer.getByteTimeDomainData(MyNamespace.audio.data)

    const WIDTH = MyNamespace.audio.canvasEl.width
    const HEIGHT = MyNamespace.audio.canvasEl.height
    const bufferLength = MyNamespace.audio.data.length
    const dataArray = MyNamespace.audio.data

    // https://github.com/mdn/voice-change-o-matic-float-data/blob/c745ba8b48d7a9b93661ac43da2886633c06f2a7/scripts/app.js#L190
    MyNamespace.audio.canvasCtx.fillStyle = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'
    MyNamespace.audio.canvasCtx.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT)

    var barWidth = (WIDTH / bufferLength) * 2.5
    var barHeight
    var x = 0

    for (var j = 0; j < bufferLength; j++) {
      // 128 means no sound? 128 corresponds to 0? Log indicates so!
      // Multiply by 2 to make it more noticable.
      barHeight = Math.abs(dataArray[j] - 128) * 2
      //console.log('bar height', barHeight)

      MyNamespace.audio.canvasCtx.fillStyle = 'rgb(' + Math.floor(barHeight + 66) + ',133,244)'
      MyNamespace.audio.canvasCtx.fillRect(x, Math.abs(HEIGHT - barHeight) / 2, barWidth, barHeight)

      x += barWidth + 1
    }

    // Animate
    MyNamespace.audio.canvasAnimation = requestAnimationFrame(drawWave)
  }
}

function createAudio() {
  if (MyNamespace.firstUserGesture) {
    // Note: As a consequence of calling createMediaElementSource(),
    // audio playback from the HTMLMediaElement will be re-routed into the processing graph of the AudioContext.
    // So playing/pausing the media can still be done through the media element API and the player controls.
    if ('webkitAudioContext' in window) {
      MyNamespace.ctx = new webkitAudioContext()
      console.log('webkitAudioContext() is available.')
    } else if ('AudioContext' in window) {
      MyNamespace.ctx = new AudioContext()
      console.log('AudioContext() is available.')
    } else {
      console.log('Web Audio API is not available.')
    }

    MyNamespace.audio.source = MyNamespace.ctx.createMediaElementSource(MyNamespace.audio.el)
    MyNamespace.audio.analyzer = MyNamespace.ctx.createAnalyser()
    MyNamespace.audio.source.connect(MyNamespace.audio.analyzer)
    MyNamespace.audio.source.connect(MyNamespace.ctx.destination)
    console.log('Web Audio API is all set')
    // We are sure Web Audio API context is ready.
    setupCanvas()
  }
  MyNamespace.firstUserGesture = false
}

function handleClick() {
  // The AudioContext is not allowed to start before user gesture.
  // It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page.
  createAudio()

  // Play/pause the media
  if (MyNamespace.audio.el.paused) {
    MyNamespace.audio.el.play()
  } else {
    MyNamespace.audio.el.pause()
  }
}

MyNamespace.audio.btnEl = document.getElementById("btn")
MyNamespace.audio.btnEl.addEventListener('click', handleClick)
```

```html
<div style="width: 100%;">
  <button id="btn">Play/pause</button>
</div>
<div style="width: 100%;">
  <audio id="aud" style="width: 50%;" preload="metadata" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <source src="https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_OOG_1MG.ogg" />
      <source src="https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3" />
      Your browser does not support the vedio tag.
    </audio>
</div>
<div style="width: 100%;">
  <canvas id="canvasEl" style="width: 88%; height: 100px;"></canvas>
</div>
```

The code works fine on all modern browsers. Except for a 2018 Safari on macOS.

A visualization sample of Opera browser on macOS is like this:

[image: Screenshot: Opera is fine on macOS]

Log indicates that Safari returns all data equal to `128`:

```
  let d = dataArray[j]
  if (d != 128) {
    console.log('data is NOT equal to 128')
  }
```

Comment: The canvas is blank in Firefox on macOS? And chrome on macOS as well

Comment: @evolutionxbox Let me check...

Comment: For details: Firefox 95.0b8 and Chrome 95.0.4638.69 on macOS 12.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Firefox 88, Chromium 75, Opera 81 on macOS are all fine. Only Safari doesn't show the canvas visualization.

Comment: That's good (it is), but it still doesn't show in the versions I've listed.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I think the code snippet I posted here has a new problem other than the original problem. Let me double-check...

Comment: @evolutionxbox I fixed the code snippet posted here :)

Comment: Can confirm that the updated snippet works in Firefox 95.0b8 and Chrome 95.0.4638.69 on macOS 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding the `MP3` file, now the code snippet of the question runs fine on Safari:

```html
<source src="https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3" />
```

Looks like Safari 12.0.3 doesn't support the `OGG` file type.